# Order-preserving maps

Tags: order-theory

If I understand correctly, order-preserving maps  are generally defined between reflexive, transitive, anti-symmetric relations (Posets). 
Does it make sense to talk about "order-preserving maps" between reflexive and transitive relations (Quasi-orderings)? Is there an equivalent term?

Answer (score 2):

*Quasi-order preserving* is fine.

Note that it makes sense to talk about a *relation-preserving* map between two sets endowed with arbitrary relations. That is, a map $f:A\to B$ such that $$\forall x,y\in A, \ \left[x\mathcal{R}_A y\implies f(x)\mathcal{R}_B f(y)\right]$$

Comment: Very clear, thank you very much!

Comment: @MatteoCorsi You're welcome!